# How to Clear illegal data type error in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I am in the process creating tab pages dynamically. For that i declared a instance in the window.

```
"uo_trans_for_tab_page_demo iuo[3]
String is_DwObjects[3]".
```

But i get a error message of :

```
Illegal datatype:uo_trans_for_tab_page_demo
```

Can any onr help me with this problem since i am beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create an array in the window to keep track of your tabpages because the tab control already does that for you in the tab's control array. Similarly, you don't need to keep the names of the dataobjects you use because the DataWindow's dataobject property will have it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to declare a user object variable (or array) the user object must be defined within the same .PBL file of the window or within your applications library list.